# Could anyone prove this property of orthonormal basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{n}$ form an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Want to prove

$$\sum_{i}^{n}\sum_{j,k}a_{ij}a_{ik}=n$$

After some numerical experiments, this is true. Also, this is a sufficient condition for another theorem.

Answer (score 1):

An orthonormal basis can be written as the image of an orthogonal matrix by writing the vectors as column vectors in a single matrix. Your inner expression is this matrix times its transpose. But for an orthogonal matrix $A$, we have $A A^T = 1$, i.e. $A^T = A^{-1}$. Then the latter sum is just taking the trace. The trace of the identity matrix is $n$, so this is your numerical observation.

Comment: Actually it is not the case. In fact, the terms in the sum are pairwise products of components of one single orthonormal basis. Then we sum all these products of all orthonormal basis together finally get the answer I conjecture.

Comment: @EricLAN Addition is commutative, so it doesn't matter whether the sum over $i$, over $j$, or over $k$ is the outermost sum.

Comment: the inner sum is not A times its transpose. Here I define a1=(a11,a12,...,a1n).

Answer (score 0):

For each $i$, {$a_{ik}$} is an orthonormal basis, so by definition $\sum _{jk}a_{ij}a_{ik}=1$.  Therefore the sum of $n$ such bases $=n$.

Comment: a counter example: $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}{2})$. The summation of this basis is 1/4+3/4+2*\sqrt(3)/4, which is not 1. But cooperating with another orthonormal basis, the summation of the two is 2.

Comment: @EricLAN  Your example doesn't look orthonormal?  Unless I misunderstand the definition, the sum should be one.